# Using javascript/REST API to access SharePoint data from CRM online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to query Onpremises SharePoint site from a html page living inside CRM online and display the list of documents from a library?

The Html page also needs to interact with Azure service bus and send messages based on the user interactions on the page.

It appears I would need to use javascript/REST API for accessing SharePoint data but I'm not clear how we handle authentication and trust between CRM and SharePoint and also if this will not result in cross domain issue.

Is it possible to post ASB messages just using jquery/REST API?